# Vertical Layout Gives Out Dimension Error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

after a long and resultless research through the whole web for this error, I have come here. As a part of a small game I am working on in Android Studio, I needed Vertical Layouts which are basically being used as lines to border some buttons. At first, everything was fine, though when I added a new vertical layout it gave out about 7 problems all at once:

```
Error:error: '270' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:'270' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:failed linking file resources.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

For the full output click [here](https://pastebin.com/eT7QpUrd)
For the XML layout click [here](https://pastebin.com/ajFatAPd)

Now I do not have much more than that to tell you, so I just hope I will find (either thanks to you or by even deeper explore) the solution.

Comment: Post your XML code.

Comment: XML layout please

Comment: I now tried to remove each and every vertical and horizontal layout, it did clean out the 7 errors, but for some reason, it does not find my activity's name in the java code. `setContentView (R.layout.activity_tic_tac_toe);` gives out `Error:(12, 33) error: cannot find symbol variable activity_tic_tac_toe` although it is the accurate and exact name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to use the unit ('270' instead of, for example, '270dp').
More info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension